# Вложенный json словарь, необходимо сделать проверку на наличие ключа в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Спарсил данные с сайта в формат json, где первый ключ- это фамилия и имя автора.

Не могу понять как написать условие, которое будет проверять, есть ли данный автор в json или нет.

Как переписать проверку, чтобы в терминал выводилось сообщение, если данный пользователь не найден?

```
[
    {
        "Артём П.": {
            "Ссылка на профиль мастера": 
            "https://workers.com//freelancers/AllXX",
            "Сфера деятельности": "Разработка",
            "Позиция в категории «Разработка»": 1
        }
    } 
]

user_input = input('Введите имя автора: ')


for i in result_json:
    if i.get(user_input) is None:
        pass
    else:
        for key, value in i.get(user_input).items():
            print(key, ':', value)

        print(f'Информация актуальна на {datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}, {datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")}\n')
```

Comment: Оффтоп. В f-строках дату можно форматировать без использования ее методов, пример: `print(f'Информация актуальна на {datetime.now():%d.%m.%Y}, {datetime.now():%H:%M:%S}\n')`

Comment: `Как переписать проверку, чтобы в терминал выводилось сообщение, если данный пользователь не найден?` вместо `pass` выводить то сообщение?

Comment: @gil9red , проблема в том, что json в моём коде- это массив со вложенными словарями. чтобы получить каждый отдельный словарь, как в примере, который я прислал, мне необходимо пройтись но массиву циклом. В цикле я сравниваю ФИО, которое ввёл пользователь с ключами словарей. Соответственно если пользователь хочет получить информацию об авторе, который находится в конце массива, то программа выведет кучу None перед тем как выведет информацию об авторе. Не знаю как можно переписать моё условие... Чтобы выводило сообщение, если автора вообще нету в списке. Заменить pass на print не лучшая идея...

Comment: @gil9red , в целом да, чтобы не выводило None и чтобы проверял все ключи словарей по очереди

Answer (score 1):

пишите , что автора нет, только если безрезультатно прошли цикл. В питоне есть для этого случая специальная конструкция for ... break else

```
   d = [
        {'a':1},
        {'b':2}
    ]
    user_input = 'c'
    for x in d:
        if user_input in x:
            print('Ура найдено')
            break
    else:
        print('такого нет')
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, посмотрю про эту конструкцию!