# Выдаёт не то что нужно

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Вот мой код:

```
block = ['fox', 'dog', 'rat']

def censorship(str_, words):
    global censoring
    for word in words:
        if str_ in word:
            censoring = 'true'
    censoring = 'false'
    print(censoring)

text = 'My son likes to play with our dog'

censorship(text, block)
```

при запуске выдаёт:

```
false
```

а должен:

```
true
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется там должно быть `word id str_` а не наоборот

Comment: Во первых, указывайте ЯП в метках. А во вторых, может он и должен выдавать `true`, но не будет, поскольку вы в любом случае этой строчкой `censoring = 'false'` делаете переменную равной `false`

Comment: Если даже поправите замечание, которое выше, то все равно получите false, т.к. 'rat' в ваше строке нет, а вы всегда бежите по циклу и переписываете ваши значения.

Comment: После выставления `true` надо поставить `break`, а выставление `false` вынести в блок `else:`, относящийся к `for`

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Очень сильно помогли.

Comment: @oneLEAM вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1481101/Вложенный-json-словарь-необходимо-сделать-проверку-на-наличие-ключа-в-словаре/1481116#1481116 вчера как раз писал примерно про предыдущий комментарий CrazyElf

Comment: @splash58 Да наверняка вопрос вообще типовой, мне сейчас некогда просто дубликаты искать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выполнении вашего кода то, что внутри цикла не важно вообще, вы потом результат перезаписываете. Нужно как-то сделать ветвление выставления результата, например так:

```
    for word in words:
        if word in str_:
            censoring = 'true'
            break
    else:
        censoring = 'false'
```

Ну и само сравнение скорее всего наоборот нужно написать.